# Youtube video in a UIWebView with small frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiwebview, youtube

In my app I'm supposed to make a menu where users can play a video from a list. The list is presented in a horizontal UIScrollView and I have a frame of 120x80 (in points, in pixels it's 240:160 on retina). The links for videos are either youtube urls or addresses of .m3u8 files on our server (I put them in a simple html from apple's http live streaming documentation).

My problem is with the youtube urls. These pages opened in UIWebView always have a bar on top that limits the tappable surface to half. Also when I play the video for first time another bar shows up (for like, dislike and things like that), which limits the space that will launch the video on tap to 0.

My goal here is to have the videos represented by images (UIImageViews) with buttons on top of them in shape of the "Play" triangle. When I press that UIButton, the video should show, as normal, inside an MPMovieController.

So I need 1 of 2 things:

- Have the UIWebView show just the video of the youtube page, without the bars.
- Make the youtube video show inside an MPMovieController after user taps a UIButton.

Any tips on how to do either of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do like this and  you need use  set property on UIWebView.look this example

[here](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me as not all videos I show can be embedded.

Comment: Now I'm using javascript solution from https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference and it was working fine for a while, but now when I try to play video I see "this video contains content from SME. It is restricted from playback on certain sites.", so I still have problems with it.